# Sorted Set with different implementations of `equals` and `compareTo`

Tags: java

I have a programme where I need to store a set of objects of a "self-made" class, let's call it `objectSet`. For this, I've overwritten the `equals` and the `hashCode` methods.

I've got an outer `while` loop and an inner `for` loop. In the outer loop I take the smallest element of `objectSet`(let's call it `e1`) and compare it with all the other elements in the inner `for` loop. For the comparison, I've overwritten the `compareTo` method of my class based on a particular property of the objects. After the inner loop is finished, `objectSet` is changed (some elements that were created within the inner loop are added and `e1` is removed). Then again, the smallest element of `objectSet` is chosen as `e1` and a new inner `for` loop is started.

As the new elements that are created during the inner `for` loop might have exactly the same values for instance variables as existing objects and I don't need duplicates, I am using a `Set`. As within the outer loop, I always need the smallest object `e1`, I decided to use `TreeSet` to keep the elements sorted. However, my `compareTo` method is not based on exactly the same properties as the `equals` method, and thus sometimes `compareTo` returns 0, while `equals` would return `false`. Thus, I had to switch from `TreeSet` to `HashSet`. To get `s1`, within each iteration of the outer loop I create a `List`out of the `HashSet` and sort this list. However, this is very inefficient and I am looking for a better solution.

To make a long story short: I am looking for an efficient data container that keeps the object it contains unique and sorted. `TreeSet` is not an option as it uses the `compareTo` method instead of the `equals` method to get rid of duplicates, while in my case the `compareTo` method might return 0 for two different objects for which `equals` would return `false`.

Thanks a lot for any advice!

EDIT: Consider e.g. a rectangle. Two rectangles are equal if their coordinates are the same (logic of the `equals` method). However, if I want to sort the rectangles according to their area (logic of the `compareTo` method), then there will be rectangles with different coordinates (`o1.equals(o2)`evaluates to `false`) that have the same area (`o1.compareTo(o2)` evaluates to `0`). I would like to keep these rectangles within the set (as long as their coordinates are different), but keep them sorted by their area.

Comment: You could simply provide a comparator to the `TreeSet` which behaves similar to your `equals()` method

Answer (score 0):

Call ur Equals inside ComparatorTo method

```
@Override
    public int compareTo(Data o) {
        if(!this.equals(o)) {
            //your logic
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The problem is that within the `if` statement, my logic will sometimes give the same value for different objects. Consider e.g. a rectangle. Two rectangles are equal if their coordinates are the same. However, if I want to sort the rectangles according to their area, then there will be rectangles with different coordinates that have the same area. I would like to keep those rectangles within the set (as long as their coordinates are different), but keep them sorted by their area.